# `cordova run --list` causes ECONNREFUSED

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile-devices

In Ionic, when a try to run this command : `ionic cordova run --list`, I get this error :

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9644E.png)

The thing is, if I run `cordova run --list`, I get the following:

```
Available android devices:
Available android virtual devices:
Nexus_5X_API_24
Pixel_2_API_28
Pixel_2_XL_API_30
```

But the nothing appears on my phone. I already checked the usb connection and the option depuration, and all is fine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When posting error messages please add the text of the error to your question instead of a screenshot. Screenshots can't be searched or cut-and-pasted. In your case the error suggests re-running with ``--verbose`` to get more information. Did you try that? If so, please add the result to your question.

Comment: okkey, y did not know that, y wrote the command again, and i get this, is too long: